# PHP Soap connection resetting instantly with no response

Tags: php, http, soap, connection

I'm fairly new to PHP Soap but I believe I have a handle on it. My issue is odd, I have installed the soap-php module on my Apache/cent OS server. After some playing I was able to connect to a public web-service and use it with the PHP methods (Using SoapClient()) So i do not thing it is an configuration error.

When i try to connect to the web service I want to consume which is hosted on a server locally here. The connection resets instantly and I get no response from the web service I'm trying to use.

I've tried to trouble shoot this myself but I've hit an impass in terms of what else to check.

I know the WSDL is there and accessible because when i put the URL into my browser I can see it. I know this service is working because it's being used by other applications.

I don't think it's a PHP/Apache setting issue because I can connect to other web-services and access methods in them.

However when I point my test app to the service that I want to use. I instantly get "The connection was reset". I have used a http siffer and I can see that there is simply no response from the machine I am trying to access as if it's not there. Below is the sniffer log.

> Client-> Server 192.168.1.190 -> 74.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> GET /contact/pipeline/bettertest.php HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.harms-software.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cookie: userinfo=XXXXXX%2CAdmin; __utma=266616727.1802384666.1343229893.1346876009.1346935926.113; __utmz=266616727.1346763531.101.17.utmcsr=millenniumcentral.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __unam=b0971f8-138bebd9a81-7d1a81ba-869; __utmc=266616727; __atuvc=60%7C32%2C0%7C33%2C0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C1%7C36; posts_rated=1750
>
> there is no response header because 
>   "The connection was reset
>             The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Now normally I would assume that there was some port blocked or some other connection issue between the two severs however I've checked. Port 80 is open on the machine hosting the WSDL. I also have no problems viewing the WSDL in my browser so I know the server is there and accessible on port 80.

Below is the php test code I am trying

```
<?php

    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

    $log = fopen("debug.log","w");
    fwrite($log,"about to create soap object!");   
    $client = new SoapClient("http://millennium.harms-software.com/MillenniumPipeline/MillenniumSDK.asmx?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1, cache_wsdl =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    fwrite($log,"created soap object!");


    $logonArgs = array('User' => 'testing', 'Password' => 'temppass');

    try{
            $logonResult = $this->client->Logon($logonArgs);

    }catch(SoapFault $soapFault){
            //if failed, display soap message sent, received, and the soapfault generated

            echo "Fault!!!";
            var_dump($soapFault);
            echo "<b>Request</b> :<br>", htmlentities($this->client->__getLastRequest()), "<br>";
            echo "<b>Response</b> :<br>", htmlentities($this->client->__getLastResponse()), "<br>";

    }

?>
```

I've tried to write out to a flat file to see if the code was executing and it seems to die right after creating the soap object. HOWEVER is I point this exact same script to another web service it works fine.

At this point I'm at a loss for what could be causing the server to reset the connection. If anyone out there has had something similar please clue me in.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Disable xdebug PHP extension if enabled, to see if this resolves your problem. I'm still trying to find the underlying error which causes this in conjunction with xdebug, but it seems related to slow or unresponsive SOAP services and may appear intermittent to you.

Comment: I think that it is in fact caused by a timeout issue. The server hosting the wsdl has a very high ping to the client requesting it and while it works about 80% of the time 20% of the time the server will not respond and we get a connection reset error. Unfortunately we do not have control over the server hosting the service so we can't extend the timeout or anything.